# Fedora stageros rosmake - undefined reference

Tags: simulation, stage, stageros, rosmake, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, trying to install stage on a working ROS (fuerte) install (verified through all tutorials), but at some point when I try to rosmake:

> /usr/bin/ld:
> CMakeFiles/bin/stageros.dir/src/stageros.o:
> undefined reference to symbol
> '_ZN2Fl4waitEd'   /usr/bin/ld: note:
> '_ZN2Fl4waitEd' is defined in DSO
> /lib/libfltk.so.1.3 so try adding it
> to the linker command line
> /lib/libfltk.so.1.3: could not read
> symbols: Invalid operation   collect2:
> error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[4]: *** [../bin/stageros] Error 1

No problems with rosdep either.

I thought this was related to this ticket, but shouldn't this be fixed? https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4441

Thanks so much for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40005/fedora-stageros-rosmake---undefined-reference/) by [user12821821](https://answers.ros.org/users/2936/user12821821/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2012-07-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2012-07-27**:
I don't know the answer, but what version of ROS you're working with will be important to answering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Fedora, that reference is supposed to be satisfied by installing `fltk-devel`.

What does this do?

```
$ rosdep install stage
```

UPDATE: try this, then check to see if the fltk package named is actually installed:

```
$ rosdep resolve fltk
```

UPDATE2: that #4441 fix was to an older version of stage (3.2.2). Fuerte has stage 4.1.1.

I can't tell whether or not that fix was ever applied upstream. It may have gotten lost in the version upgrade.

I recommend opening a new ticket for Fuerte, referring back to #4441 and to this question.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user12821821](https://answers.ros.org/users/2936/user12821821/) on 2012-07-27**:
When I do "rosdep install stage" I get the message: "#All required rosdeps installed successfully" then when I retry rosmake I get the exact same error.

**Comment by [user12821821](https://answers.ros.org/users/2936/user12821821/) on 2012-07-27**:
When I do "rosdep resolve fltk" I get the message: "#yum" followed by the message "fltk-devel" , when I retry rosmake I get the exact same error.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-28**:
Does yum say `fltk-devel` is actually installed?

**Comment by [user12821821](https://answers.ros.org/users/2936/user12821821/) on 2012-07-29**:
When I do yum list installed I have entries for : "fltk.i686", "fltk-devel.i686", "fltk-fluid.i686" and all of these three have a version of 1.3.0-4.fc17 thanks so much for your help btw it is greatly appreciated.

**Comment by [user12821821](https://answers.ros.org/users/2936/user12821821/) on 2012-07-30**:
Okay thanks so much for your help, submitted a ticket #5507

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone still having issues, this patch fixes things for fedora: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/attachment/ticket/5507/fltk-find-package.patch

---

Originally posted by [cottsay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3167/cottsay/) with karma: 311 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user12821821](https://answers.ros.org/users/2936/user12821821/) on 2013-03-07**:
Thanks for the update!